# "Quizá puede" vs "quizá pueda": presente indicativo vs presente subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, presente-indicativo

Ejemplo:

> Quizá esto **puede** servirte como inspiración

vs

> Quizá esto **pueda** servirte como inspiración

Desde un punto de vista teórico, ¿qué forma es correcta y por qué? Desde un punto de vista práctico, ¿importa?

Comment: Una pregunta que a priori puede parecer simple pero no lo es en absoluto, a juzgar por el espacio que la _Gramática_ le dedica. Espero que te sirva mi respuesta, y ¡bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: Ambas son tootalmente correctas. Pero el subjuntivo tiene un matiz de "duda". El subjuntivo enfatiza la duda. El otro es menos dudoso, a veces se usa como sugerencia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta duda la resuelven los [párrafos 25.14i y siguientes](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pehlLdhrzodSthko) de la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española*, el cual cito a continuación:

> Los adverbios de duda y de posibilidad son compatibles con los dos modos [indicativo y subjuntivo] dentro de su propia oración. El subjuntivo puede aparecer en estas construcciones, pero solo si el adverbio precede al verbo [...].

Es el caso de tu ejemplo, el cual podemos reordenar así para verlo con más claridad:

> Esto quizá {puede ~ pueda} servirte como inspiración.

La *Gramática* cita como ejemplo:

> *Quizá {oyó ~ oyera} la conversación.

Ya sobre el uso específico de *quizá*, el párrafo 25.14k dice:

> El adverbio *quizá(s)* suele rechazar el indicativo cuando se combina con el tiempo presente usado con valor de futuro. Se prefiere, pues, la segunda opción en *Quizás {voy ~ vaya} mañana a la ciudad*.  Cabe pensar que este contraste se debe a la colisión semántica que se produce entre el significado del adverbio *quizá(s)* y el sentido de 'decisión firme' que se asigna generalmente al presente prospectivo. La elección del modo en los demás contextos depende en gran medida de cómo se interprete la estructura informativa de la oración y, en particular, de que se enfatice o no la verosimilitud de lo que se presenta como probable o la certeza —presente o futura— de lo que aparece como inseguro.

A continuación cita los siguientes ejemplos, entre otros:

> - *Quizá no debí hacerlo: quizá debí ser más discreta.*
> - *Tal vez eran impostores, tal vez hubo entre ellos un ajuste de cuentas.*
> - *Quizás no lo pudo evitar, quizás dejó que todo ocurriera así.*

Y concluye:

> El subjuntivo es posible en estos textos si el que habla desea relativizar aún más su aserto, como sucede en *Tal vez fuese una de sus reacciones infantiles, frescas, que tanto enamoraban a Aldo*.

El párrafo 25.14l profundiza un poco más:

> El subjuntivo es algo más frecuente con los adverbios de duda cuando la información que introducen no es focal, lo que permite que la atención del hablante o del oyente se centre en algún otro segmento del discurso. Así, el que dice *Estoy buscando a alguien que quizás trabaje aquí* presenta la búsqueda de cierta persona como información central o nuclear, mientras que la oración de relativo agrega determinado dato que desea presentar como circunstancial.

No parece ser el caso de tu ejemplo. El párrafo 25.14m introduce otra alternativa:

> [...] también en estas construcciones alterna el presente de subjuntivo con el futuro, particularmente en las oraciones de sentido prospectivo en las que se hace referencia a contenidos no experimentados. Así, *consiga* alterna con *conseguirá* (no con *consigue*) en la apódosis del siguiente periodo condicional: *Si está en mi bando, quizá consiga soportar todo esto*.

Este ejemplo parece concordar un poco más con tu ejemplo, en el que se menciona algo que aún no se ha experimentado y por tanto la oración tiene sentido prospectivo. Por tanto cabría introducir como alternativa el uso del futuro:

> Quizá esto {pueda ~ podrá} servirte como inspiración.

Pero añade al final:

> Cabe hacer notar que en el último siglo se atestigua un notable decrecimiento del futuro en favor del subjuntivo en estos contextos [...].

Hasta aquí lo que dice la teoría, ahora viene la práctica. En la práctica yo te diría que la frase expresada en subjuntivo me suena mejor, por el carácter de probabilidad e inseguridad que aporta el que habla, haciendo que lo expresado sea una opinión subjetiva. Pero si usas el presente o el futuro de indicativo como alternativas se te va a entender igualmente, aunque quizá causarás en el oyente la misma duda de *¿Eso está bien dicho?*

Por último, nótese que como afirman DGaleano [en comentarios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27368/quiz%C3%A1-puede-vs-quiz%C3%A1-pueda-presente-indicativo-vs-presente-subjuntivo/27371?noredirect=1#comment46066_27371) y Ustanak en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27369/12637), puede haber diferencias regionales en su uso, aunque estas pueden ser sutiles y no afectan al entendimiento de la frase.

Comment: Todo esto muy interesante y correcto, pero yo agregaría que también se presentan diferencias regionales. Aquí en Colombia usaríamos "Quizá esto pued**a** servir**te a ti**" hablándole a una persona de confianza y "Quizá esto pued**e** servir**le a usted**" hablándole a una persona más respetuosamente.

Comment: @DGaleano claro, pero ¿qué tiene que ver tratar a una persona de tú o usted con el uso del infinitivo o el subjuntivo? En ambos casos podrías decir "puede/a servirte a ti" o "puede/pueda servirle a usted".

Comment: Si, claro. Completamente de acuerdo. Ambas funcionan y ambas son correctas, pero en Colombia siempre preferimos una para cada trato. Solo quería anotar sobre las *preferencias regionales*

Comment: @DGaleano solo para que quede claro, ¿te refieres a que usarías el subjuntivo si tratas de tú y el indicativo si tratas de usted?

Comment: Para que quede "más" claro. Usaría **puede usted** y **puedas tu** y repito, no es que considere que "pueda usted" es incorrecto.

Answer (score 2):

El adverbio *quizá* expresa duda o probabilidad; por tanto, la elección del subjuntivo es adecuada para mantener esta consistencia. No obstante, las formas

> —Quizá esto **puede / pueda** [...]

se usan *intercambiablemente* a pesar de que la con subjuntivo es correcta.
Muchas veces, los hablantes no distinguen su uso; sin embargo, y dependiendo de la región en que te encuentres, puede haber preferencia tanto en la primera como en la segunda forma.

Comment: No sé si diría que lo más adecuado es indicativo desde un punto de vista teórico.  *Quizá(s)* equivale a *posiblemente*, pero al usar ese adverbio solo se emplea el indicativo: *posiblemente esto puede servirte*.  No obstante, el uso mayoritario es con subjuntivo, con el cual, se puede justificar el uso en tal modo.

Comment: Justo lo que comenté en la respuesta de Charlie. Las preferencias regionales son importantes en este caso.